# What is wrong with my cactus? (Red spots)

Tags: diagnosis, cactus

[image: Is it dying?]

Is it dying? There are these weird red marks, is this a fungal infection or sunburn?

Comment: What are the climatic conditions for the plant's location?  And is it outside, inside, or newly either?

Comment: This plant appears to be very stressed. This is not a normal healthy look with red dots. This plant is cold-sensitive. Is it in an area where it gets below 50 degrees F? Have any other conditions changed?

Comment: That looks like too much water. Is that regular potting soil I see? Fungi can do that too, but again, they thrive on too much water.

Comment: They are jungle cactus, after all.